# Pade approximant of infinite order

Tags: approximation, rational-functions, pade-approximation

The Pade approximant states that you can approximate a function $f(x)$ by a rational function $R(x)$ of a given order. My question is, if the order of $R(x)$ goes to infinity, does $R(x)$ approach $f(x)$ exactly?

Comment: The situation is more complicated than your brief problem statement would suggest.  On what domain is the function $f(x)$ given to be approximated?  How smooth is $f(x)$?  More importantly, the Padé approximations typically exist not as a simple sequence of increasing "order", but rather as a two-dimensional net with numerators and denominators of increasing orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write the Maclaurin series of the rational function $R(x)$ you'll obtain the terms of the original function up until the specified order, since $R(x)$ is constructed so that $R(0)=f(0), R'(0)=f'(0) \cdots R^{(m+n)}(0)=f^{(m+n)}(0)$. If it is constructed to have the exact same Maclaurin expansion, then obviously it becomes $f(x)$ however this defeat the purpose of the Padé Approximation, which is used to simplify functions in the design of Control Systems for example.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes I agree it defeats the purpose for practical applications. I just was wondering from a theoretical standpoint if a rational function of infinite order converges to the original function. So for example, with the time delay in control systems, the Pade approximant of $e^{-sT}$ actually converges to $e^{-sT}$ when the order goes to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

[image] Guess how this wonderful plot is generated? Surely enough, while applying pade approximation of a given system, where delay function is located at the feedback path. As it can be seen, the dominant pole of the system is unmoved because of the approximation, but, higher order pole-zero pair moves towards infinity with increasing order of pade approximation. Sure enough, all the non-dominant poles are coupled with zeros, which signifies, system response is unaltered because of the approximation.

NB: I am talking from control system/transfer point of view. OC may pardon me for that.

Comment: While the context of your plot is no doubt familiar to you, there is insufficient information provided for Readers to "guess" how it relates to increasing the order of Padé approximations (which is a fairly complicated matter, already abbreviated by the way the Question was posed).

Comment: That's correct. But the equations  in regards to the system is another topic of discussion. So it is not provided. But, I want the readers to appreciate and discuss, how the poles of the system moves without impacting onto the system, when pade approximation is applied. Do you suggest me delete this answer? Is it irrelevant here?

Comment: The Question asks about what happens when "the order" of Padé approximants increases "to infinity".  Even a concrete example of what *might* occur would be of some value, but you've not specfied what function $f(x)$ and what orders of approximation are being plotted.  If you can supply these, your example could well be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I will try.